# Changing button text based on language settings need to refresh the page in angular

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am using **ngx-translate** for the internationalization of my app. In my HTML page I am using translate pipe to change the language. The example is below:

```
<app-pagetitle title="{{ 'PAGES.DASHBOARD' | translate }}"></app-pagetitle>
```

In one of my form, I need to change the button text based on condition from TS file. Here is the code:

```
this.translateService.get('BUTTON_TEXT.SAVE_BUTTON').subscribe((translatedString) => {
                    this.saveButtonLabel = translatedString;
                 });
```

and my language json file is:

```
    {
    "PAGES": {
            "DASHBOARD": "Dashboard",
            "WHITEBOARD": "Whiteboard"
        },
        "BUTTON_TEXT": {
            "SAVE_BUTTON": "Save",
            "UPDATE_BUTTON": "Update"
        }

}
```

**Now the problem is button text is not changing whenever I change the language from topbar. I need to refresh the page.** Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try & let me know if this work:
`
constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectionRef ) {}
...
this.translateService.get('PAGES.DASHBOARD').subscribe((translatedString) => {
   this.saveButtonLabel = translatedString;
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
});
`

Comment: what is the import statement for "ChangeDetectionRef". or do I need to install any package?

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of ways to resolve this and the one solution I can think of is to manually triggering Change Detection:

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
...
constructor(
  ...
  private cdr: ChangeDetectionRef
) {}
...
this.translateService.get('PAGES.DASHBOARD')
  .subscribe((translatedString) => {
    this.saveButtonLabel = translatedString;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
});
```

Another solution that I can think of is to use `async` pipe & for that you need to tweak your code a bit:

```js
saveButtonLabel: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
...
this.translateService.get('PAGES.DASHBOARD')
  .subscribe((translatedString) => {
    this.saveButtonLabel.next(translatedString);
});
```

```html
<button>{{ saveButtonLabel | async }}</button>
```

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Can you `console.log(translatedString)` & check if you're actually getting some output?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the output

Comment: Can you create a small working demo on Stackblitz